# Parallax scroll-Text from previous page showing up on top of next page

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax scroll effect not just for the background image but also for the text on my page. I managed to get it to work for the background image and tried using z-index for the various text but that hasn't worked either.

Is there a way to do this similar to what I've tried using just CSS or am I going down the complete wrong avenue/need to use JavaScript?

The HTML I've written is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
                <div class="about_me_background">
                    <div id="hyperlink_list" class="container centered ambroise_text" style="top: 5%; width: 1250px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="ambroise_text" style="font-weight: 500;" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a class="ambroise_text" style="font-weight: 500;" href="">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a class="ambroise_text" style="font-weight: 500;" href="">SYNTHETIC CHEMISTRY</a></li>
                        <li><a class="ambroise_text" style="font-weight: 500;" href="">SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                        <h1 class="centered ambroise_text bottom_border" style="font-size: 65px; width: 812.6px;">
                            MY NAME
                        </h1>
                        <p class="centered ambroise_text" style="letter-spacing: 4px; font-size: 35px; font-weight: 100; top: 52%;">
                            Interactive resume
                        </p>
                </div>
                <div class="background_white">
                    <div id="profile" class="container ambroise_text" style="color: #22A39F;">
                        <h2>Profile</h2>
                        <p class="lead ambroise_text" style="color: #727878;">
                            Synthetic chemist with a strong interest in software engineering
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-md-4 ambroise_text">
                            <h3 style="color: #22A39F;">About me</h3>
                            <p style="color: #000000; letter-spacing: 4px; text-justify: auto;">
                                Since graduating in 2018 I have worked in the materials science industry specialising in organic synthetic chemistry and polymerisations. Specifically I work in the synthesis of fluorescent polymer nanoparticles for use in cancer diagnosis and general histopathology. I also have a keen interest in software development and
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <img src="" alt="photo of me" width="246" height="246">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 ambroise_text">
                            <h3 style="color: #22A39F;">Details</h3>
                            <p>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the relevant CSS code is:

```
.about_me_background{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HUSl.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

.background_white{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

.centered{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.ambroise_text{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: ambroise-std, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom_border{
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Also apologies I tried adding the URL of the first background image but it didn't work. Heres the imgur url if you want to download it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HUSl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but try to add `z-index` to the centered class:

```
.centered{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
/* add z-index */
  z-index : -1;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it by changing the centered class position property to absolute. Thanks anyway!